# Override Order Confirmation Button

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I am trying to override the order confirmation button using a custom module. My aim is to change the prefix in the order name when the order is confirmed.
For example, when a quotation A-130715-003 is confirmed, the name should change to AB-130715-003 (note the B that is added).The rest of the name should remain unchanged.

Here is my code so far.

```
def action_button_confirm(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    """
    Changes the quotation sequence by adding a B.
    """
    for sale in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=None):
        sequenc = sale.name
        sequenc = sequenc[:1] + 'B' + sequenc[1:]
        self.write(cr, uid, [sale.id], {
            'name': sequenc
        })
    return super(sale_offer, self).action_button_confirm(cr, uid, ids, context=context)
```

This is however not working. Kindly help with any ideas.

Comment: correct the spell of sale_order instead of sale_offer. Method seems fine.

Comment: Hi @AtulArvind. Thats my class name in which I am inheriting sale.order model

Answer (score 0):

Then you should edit the sequence from sale_order and not the confirm button. Sequences are located in ir.sequence or under the settings.

These sequences contain prefixes, suffixes, etc...

Answer (score 0):

You overide wrong function should be wkf_action_confirm .